# Sqlite on embedded device

Tags: sqlite, memory, embedded

Scenario: i want to use SQLITE on embedded device with an eMMC instead of magnetic hard disk. All flash memories have a limited write cycles. All recent memories have a wear leveling system that allow to increase the lifetime of the memory. Each write is distribuited on the whole address space of the device (mapping between logical address and physical address). The main problem with a flash memory is the Write Amplification Factor (WAF): when you want to write some data into the memory the minimum amount of memory that will be written is the whole memory page (1, 2 or 4 KB depends on memory). So if you want to write 1 bit or 900 bytes you will write 1 page of 1 KB (example).

Suppose to have a SQLITE table with id (integer autoincrement), timestamp (integer indexed) and data (string not indexed).
It's possible to predict (overestimation) of the number of bytes written for each INSERT?

Scenario example: INSERT INTO table (timestamp,data) VALUES (140909090,"The data limited to 100 bytes").

Note that in my scenario normally the timestamp will increase because is the real timestamp of the datalogging.

It's possibile to predict that foreach insert 8 (id) + 8 (timestamp) + max 100 bytes (data) will be written for each insert. But what about the write overhead of id and timestamp indexes?

Comment: Log all writes, and just measure yourself.

Comment: Doesn't SQLite rewrite the whole file for every update?

Comment: No ... for any update of not indexed fields sqlite write only the real data. For indexed fields sqlite can rewrite the index (not the whole database i hope)